# What's the word for the "We'll use these words" heading in a technical document?

Tags: single-word-requests

SAMPLE "SENTENCE":

> 1.1.3 Vocab
>
> A "unit test" is any test which only needs the system under test
>
> A
> "functional test" is one which needs other systems, e.g. databases,
> interwebsites, users.

I'm seeking the correct term instead of "Vocab"

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/whatstheword/comments/5b6okj/whats_the_word_for_the_well_use_these_words/

Comment: "Terminology", "lexicon".

Comment: *Glossary*, perhaps?

Comment: Glossary sounded right, but Chambers says, not quite: http://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=Glossary&title=21st

Comment: "Terminology used in this document" is a good usage. But isn't there another term, for the heading?

Comment: "Definitions" is the one I most often see in technical documents.

Comment: OTOH, modern tech writers do not use the "at the end of a book" qualifier, so "glossary" sounds better. http://www.techscribe.co.uk/techw/glossary.htm#glossary

Comment: @SimonB, what do you work in? I don't remember much of it as a Software Engineer. And now that you mention it I think I *should* have seen it more often

Comment: @jalanb Strangely enough, I'm also in software.  It may be a local documentation convention.

Comment: How about "Key Terms"?

Comment: @MatthewWoo, there's certainly a [Glossary of Key Terms](http://writing.colostate.edu/guides/guide.cfm?guideid=90) in [a collection of Writing Guides](http://writing.colostate.edu/guides/), which seems a definitively [citable source](http://writing.colostate.edu/guides/citation.cfm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is “Nomenclature”. Perhaps slightly narrower in scope than “Terminology” suggested by @pauljohnson.

The [Oxford Online Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomenclature) gives:

> **nomenclature**
>
> 1[mass noun] The devising or choosing of names for things, especially in a science or other discipline.
>
> 1.1 The body or system of names used in a particular specialist field.

Answer (score 1):

I work with lots of technical documents. The headings I see most often for the definitions of technical terms within a document are are "Glossary" and "Terminology".